# webextension background page vs add-on SDK page-worker cross-domain permission

Tags: firefox-addon, cross-domain, firefox-addon-sdk, webrequest

The webwxtensions docs says: in order to do the same work done by the page-worker  add-on framework, I must to use the background page, or load remote iframes into the background page

manifest.json file

```
{
  "description": "Page worker with webextensions",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "backgroundpage",
  "version": "1.2",

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "webRequest"
  ]
}
```

background.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="msg" type="text" value="ok"/>
<iframe id="ifr" src="" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
<iframe id="ifr2" src="" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

background.js file

```
console.log("BACKGROUND SCRIPT browser console");
var l1 = "http://www.example.com/";
var l2 = "http://www.google.com";

setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('ifr').src = l1;
},1000);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('ifr2').src = l2;
},1500);


setTimeout(function(){

    try{
        var iframe = document.getElementById('ifr');
        var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        console.log("FROM BG " + innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);
    }catch(e){console.log("error l1 " + e);}
    try{
        var iframe = document.getElementById('ifr2');
        var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        console.log("FROM BG " + innerDoc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);
    }catch(e){console.log("error l2 " + e);}


},10000);
```

www.example.com permits cross domain
www.google.com doesn't permitt cross domain

on both cases I got:
error l1 Error: Permission denied to access property "document"  background.js:20:15
error l2 Error: Permission denied to access property "document"  background.js:25:15

With the add-on sdk Page-worker is very simply to load invisible webpage and attachscript on it

Where is the problem in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.